# R - Dplyr - Comparing values from last row vs actual row

Tags: r, dplyr

I've this data frame:

```
    year    month    UserID
1   2014    11        3527
2   2014    12        4916
3   2015    1         2445
```

**And want to add a "Variation" column: The formula would be: ActualRow/LastRow - 1.**

This is my code:

```
UserID_unicos2 <- UserID_unicos1 %>%
                  mutate(variation=(UserID/lag(UserID) - 1)) %>% 
                  mutate(prev=lag(UserID))
```

However, it just returns:

```
    year    month   UserID  variation   prev
1   2014     11      3527      NA        NA
2   2014     12      4916   0.3938191   3527
3   2015      1      2445      NA        NA
```

As you see, it just return values for 2014-12. And not for:  2015-01. How come? Thanks.

My data after applying "dput()":

```
structure(list(year = c(2014L, 2014L, 2015L), month = c(11L, 
12L, 1L), UserID = c(3527L, 4916L, 2445L)), .Names = c("year", 
"month", "UserID"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = list(year), drop = TRUE, indices = list(
    0:1, 2L), group_sizes = c(2L, 1L), biggest_group_size = 2L, labels = structure(list(
    year = 2014:2015), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), .Names = "year", vars = list(year)))
```

Comment: @akrun, I've dplyr 0.4.1, i don't understand this "dplyr::mutate(variation=..)", where should i put that? thanks.

Comment: It may be a grouping issue.  I didn't use your `dput` as it had some issues

Comment: @akrun, same data returned, when using: UserID_unicos1 %>% dplyr::mutate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to your `dput`, your data is grouped by `year` and that is why you see this outcome. Try this instead:

```
UserID_unicos1 %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(variation=(UserID/lag(UserID) - 1),
         prev=lag(UserID))
```

Also note that you can create both columns in the same `mutate` just separated by comma.